# How to print the result of a .ps1 in windows form?

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms, runspace

I'm creating a system for executing cascaded scripts. There will be a checklist and depending on the option that the user selects, he must execute these lines inside the powershell (.ps1). So that the user can follow the application status of the selected items, I want to print the execution status on the screen. I'm using C# the current command I'm using opens the powershell, and I don't want to make it available to the user.

Code

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command command = new Command(@"E:\Users\goku\Downloads\Baseline1.ps1");
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Ybu.png)

my idea is that this window opens to show the status and when it's done it closes automatically, I don't want to leave an exit button.

thank you if anyone can help.

I didn't find anything that would make it possible to print the result.

Comment: Looks like you output is using WinForm and you took a textbox and made multiline.  What is wrong with that solution?  In Power shell you can use Write-Host to display the table or pipe results to Format-Table : $variable | Format-Table

Comment: If you want the look of Winform inside powershell,  you should check out Out-Gridview.  You can see the help file [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.3).